# MYSQL query takes too long on server, on localhost however it works fine

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query which helped me save from PHP pain, but if the results are increased, now I get to see, this same query halts my application. Which is worse

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM table1
               INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.somecolumn = table2.somecolumn
         WHERE     (   table1.statuscolumn = 'status1'
                    OR table1.statuscolumn = 'status2')
               AND table2.othercolumn2 = 'somevalue'
               AND table1.othercolumn
               AND table1.othercolumn LIKE
                      CONCAT('%', table3.othercolumn3, '%'))
          AS utilization
  FROM table3, table1
 WHERE     table3.othercolumn2 = 'somevalue'
       AND (   table1.statuscolumn = 'status1'
            OR table1.statuscolumn = 'status2')
       AND table3.othercolumn4 = 'on'
GROUP BY table3.othercolumn3
```

How can I achieve same results within less execution time. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have indexes set up?

Comment: No indexes at all. Some of the columns like othercolumn2 is an index but not for any of tables of this query. :(

Comment: You have no join conditions between the tables.  That is usually a sign of a major problem in a query.

Comment: Hardly I know this, I wrote this query too in hours.  @GordonLinoff , I supposed whilst writing no join is needed.

Comment: Please some more suggestions and I will be done with it. Thank you.

Comment: Your code won't run. look at the line with your 'LIKE' clause and decide which do you want: `table2.othercolumn2 = 'somevalue'` or `table2.othercolumn2 LIKE
                                        CONCAT('%',table3.othercolumn3,'%')`. See [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm) for help with `LIKE` in `WHERE` clause

Comment: You have 2 clauses in the sub-select which make little sense - `AND table1.othercolumn` only really works if this column is a boolean (it may be) and `table2.othercolumn2 = 'somevalue' LIKE CONCAT('%',table3.othercolumn3,'%')` doesn't make much sense at all (IMHO)!

Comment: No, Sorry, I messed up while pasting here. 
This one AND follows. 
AND table1.othercolumn
                LIKE
 CONCAT('%',table3.othercolumn3,'%')
I want this one. @bc004346

Comment: AND table1.othercolumn is not boolean but a string separated by comma like 1,2,3..., whose parts are in CONCAT table column othercolumn3 @NigelRen

Comment: Please `edit` your question and as your comments are confusing

Answer (score 0):

Though it is hard to give a precise answer without having a good quality question, I'm going to give it a try:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
    ADD INDEX (somecolumn);

ALTER TABLE table2
    ADD INDEX (somecolumn);

ALTER TABLE table1
    ADD INDEX (statuscolumn);

ALTER TABLE table2
    ADD INDEX (othercolumn2);

ALTER TABLE table3
    ADD INDEX (othercolumn2);

ALTER TABLE table3
    ADD INDEX (othercolumn4);
```

Comment: This will alter my tables which frankly I am not authorized to. Somehow instead of using sub queries within, I am fetching the results and running sub queries for each othercolumn. Which is taking way lesser execution time and now application is not halting at all. Thank you for your support, all !

Comment: So... how do you expect to optimize the query if you don't have access to modify the table? Dude, you are wasting our time